# Constructors inheritance vs methods inheritance in C++ objects

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there a way under C++ to have the object methods inheritance acting like constructors inheritance? 
Let's have the following:

```
(myclass.h)

class B{
public:
    B();

    void doSomething();
};

class A : public B{
public:
    A();

    void doSomething();
}

(myclass.cpp)

B::B()
{
    executeBCode();
}

void B::doSomething()
{
    executeBCode();
}

A::A : B()
{
    executeACode();
}

void A::doSomething()
{
    executeACode();
}
```

What happens is that calling the A constructor, I execute the `executeBCode()` and then the `executeACode()`. With method call `doSomething()` on A object I execute just the `executeACode()`, because it's overridden.
Is there a way to have inheritance on methods behave like inheritance on constructors, so executing both the derived and base code?
I came into this question because I need that the base class in my code does something for its derived class, and moreover the derived should execute its own instructions: this simply calling the `doSomething()` function on the derived.
This could be the case of a `closeAll()` method called on A for example, where the base class close its own base objects and the derived its specific stuff.

Comment: You could just add a call to `B::doSomething();` to the `void A::doSomething()` function. Else investigate the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Calling `B::doSomething();` on A means that inheritance in useless. I can't unsterstand why it has not been implemented in C++ language with a keyword on base method. And maybe in others programming languages too...

Comment: `doSomething` is not overridden, it's just hidden by another function with the same name. Overriding means replacing a virtual function and you have no virtual functions.

Comment: _"means that inheritance in useless"_ This is a totally stupid statement. Inheritance has lots of uses, the fact it doesn't do one thing you want does not make it "useless". Base classes _must_ be created and destroyed, so calls to their constructors and destructors sometimes happen implicitly. It is not true that base class functions _must_ be called, so calls to them are not implicit when there happens to be a function with the same signature in a derived class, you need to call the base function explicitly.

Comment: "means that inheritance in useless" ... to solve this specific case. Since one of the suggested solutions is a direct call to the base function

Comment: One of the principles of C++ is not to add new keywords to do things that can be achieved using more general language features. The answers below show how to achieve it without magic new language features, and those solutions are more flexible because you can control exactly what gets executed in what order.

Comment: Here there are NOT stupid statements or stupid answers, if we are here posting something is just for a lack in knowledge, we are not in a forum discussing politic

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible directly, however you can achieve something close enough by using the [Non-virtual interface idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) the following way:

```
class A {
public:
    void someFunction() {
        //put the base's code here
        someFuncImpl();//Calls the private function here
        //or here, as you see fit
    }        
private:
    virtual void someFuncImpl();//potentially pure: = 0;
};
```

and then in another class:

```
class B : public A {
private:
    virtual void someFuncImpl() {
        //Derived's code goes here
    }
};
```

That way, when you call `someFunction()` on class `B`, you'll have both the code of the derived class *and* the code of the base class executed each time.

That's not as simple as the way constructors can do it, but I think that's the closest and simplest you'll get. You get as a bonus the choice to run the base's code before or after the derived's code.

Comment: No, but I forgot to declare `B` as a `public A`. You don't need to declare `someFunction()` in `B` because as it inherits `A`, it has the member function as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent here, it is not possible to do this directly in the language (it may be in other languages). There are two alternative mechanisms/techniques that can be used to achieve a similar result.

A call to the base function from the derived class's function would work;

```
void A::doSomething()
{
    B::doSomething();
    executeACode();
}
```

Using the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) (as used in the C++ IO streams library), also known as the [NVI - non virtual interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern), would also work;

```
class B {
    void executeBCode();
    virtual void doSomethingImp() = 0; // or not pure
public:
    void pubDoSomething() { // public facing
        executeBCode(); // order these as required
        doSomethingImp();
    }
};

class A {
    void executeACode();
    void doSomethingImp() override // internal implementation
    {
        executeACode();
    }
};
```

Comment: In the last example, calling `A.doSomething()` results in executing just the `executeACode();`

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in mechanism outside of constructors and destructors.

Closest you can get is calling the base methods yourself, or using the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

```
class B{
public:
    B();
    void doSomething();
};

class A : public B{
public:
    A();
    void doSomething()
    {
       B::doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think an example of calling the base function would greatly enhance this answer.